# Is there a desktop environment in which I can have the launcher/panel on my secondary monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, launcher

I have two monitors, one of which is 1920x1080 and the other is 1280x1024. I have the smaller monitor on the left. In Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, I can put the launcher on the left-hand monitor; however, I can't seem to make the right-hand monitor the primary display when doing this. This is an issue for full screen games and applications, which go on the left, smaller monitor when I really want them on my big one. Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds in Unity? Failing that, is there a different desktop environment which can solve my problem?

Comment: You can use CompizConfigSettingsManager (CCSM) to specify which applications go on what screen/monitor.  But you cannot (from Ubuntu) change the primary monitor unless your BIOS supports it... (AFAIK)